# How to forward internet traffic of port 51413 to go through 127.0.0.1:8443?

Tags: networking, proxy, transmission

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 MATE. I have installed the C library of shadowsocsk-libev, and I connect to my server using `ss-local -c /etc/shadowsocks.json` . and I get the following output:

```
 2024-02-13 20:38:21 INFO: initializing ciphers... chacha20-ietf-poly1305
 2024-02-13 20:38:21 INFO: listening at 127.0.0.1:8443
```

if I set Firefox to use the proxy server listening at 127.0.0.1:8443 then it works well. I have on my system the torrent client "Transmissions", which is set by default to use port 51413, and I don't think it works when I change the port. I feel like there should be some simple GNU CLI tool that would do this simple task for me, that is to forward transmissions's internet traffic or that of port 51413 through 127.0.0.1:8443. Transmissions works properly if I use the GUI client V2rayA, but I can't read the source code of the program to understand how it works, and I don't prefer to use it as it is heavy on computer resources, and documented mostly in Chinese.